# Issue with attachments in ui5 application having Notes database as the backend

Tags: json, base64, lotus-notes, sapui5

I am developing an application in ui5. The 'Model' is a notes database. Now, I am fetching the notes document via JSON. I want to display the attachments in the upload collection in ui5. The JSON is returning attachments but I am unable to understand it. For e.g. I have attached a PDF document, but the JSON is showing as if I have attached 3 different files. Also the file is in Base64 format.

I want to be able to download and upload the attachments.

Following is the attachment field details in the JSON(There is only 1 file "Domino Access Service.pdf" in the field and nothing else):

```
"Attach_ProductDetails":
    {
        "type":"multipart",
        "content":        [
                    {
            "contentType":"multipart\/mixed; Boundary=\"0__=4EBB0B01DFD9A4D28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B01DFD9A4D2\""
          },
                    {
            "contentType":"multipart\/alternative; Boundary=\"1__=4EBB0B01DFD9A4D28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B01DFD9A4D2\"",
            "boundary":"--0__=4EBB0B01DFD9A4D28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B01DFD9A4D2"
          },
                    {
            "contentType":"text\/plain; charset=US-ASCII",
            "data":"                          (See attached file: 1. Domino Access Service.pdf)",
            "boundary":"--1__=4EBB0B01DFD9A4D28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B01DFD9A4D2"
          },
                    {
            "contentType":"text\/html; charset=US-ASCII",
            "contentDisposition":"inline",
            "data":"<html><body><i>(See attached file: 1. Domino Access Service.pdf)<\/i><\/body><\/html>\r\n",
            "boundary":"--1__=4EBB0B01DFD9A4D28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B01DFD9A4D2"
          },
                    {
            "contentType":"application\/pdf; name=\"1. Domino Access Service.pdf\"",
            "contentID":"<1__=4EBB0B01DFD9A4D28f9e8a93df93869091@local>",
            "contentDisposition":"attachment; filename=\"1. Domino Access Service.pdf\"",
            "contentTransferEncoding":"base64",
            "data":"<Base64 data>",
            "boundary":"--0__=4EBB0B01DFD9A4D28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B01DFD9A4D2"
          }
        ]
    }
```

It will be great help if anyone has the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is not giving you three files. It is showing you two alternative renderings of the rich text field called Attach_ProductDetails which contains the icon representing the attached file - which it thinks you might want. There could also be other data in that rich text field. The API has no idea what part of it you want, so it gives you everything - and in case you're not prepared to deal with text/html it also gives you a text/plain rendering, too.

It is also giving you the file attachment data, tagged with the "application/pdf" content-type. You need to decode the base64 data and store it so you can display it (or whatever else your application wants to do with it).